# Ways to stop a program calling home?

Tags: communication

I have an upcoming project (legit) that requires me to stop our software calling home yet tricking the program into thinking it is still legit(which it is). What sort of techniques are the best to use for this type of project. The software is written specifically for one version of the software.

Any language welcome :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well... how does it call home? Assuming you are testing something along the lines of how easy it is to pirate your software, what sort of level of knowledge is an outsider meant to have about the inner workings of the software? Etc, etc. Basically, we need some more details please.

Comment: Meaningless question, bad tags, voting to close.

Comment: Don't hardcode your phone number in it?

Comment: If this is a legit project you will have the source code. In this case all you have to do is implement a provider model for the application, which gives it options as to how it validates.

Comment: Calling someone a tool is not the right way to get the answers you want.

Answer (score 2):

To trick the program, you will have to either replace the server, or disable the calling home function.

Monitor the communication between the program and the call home server with a traffic monitor like wireshark. If the protocol is simple enough and does not employ any kind of secure authentication (i.e. a server certificate), you can replace the server with something that acts alike. Deploy a fake server, and redirect name server lookups from the original server to that server.

To disable the calling home function, you will have to reverse engineer the program. Depending on the language the program is written in, and the level of obfuscation, you may be able to decompile it to more or less high-level constructs. In principle, you want to disable the whole home-calling part, and trick the return value of that function to return 'Yes, I have successfully called home'.

Usually, the security engineer of that software will have taken precautions to make that as messy as possible.

Comment: Reverse engineering and monitoring the network traffic should be unnecessary - if it was a legit project the people working on it should have access to the source code.

Comment: Yer I do have full access to source code , but the server idea was helpful thanks :)

Comment: @slugster: In an ideal world, yes. ;)

Comment: I don't think he has access to the source code when he has to specify (legit) in his question.